# Finding point of intersection where k is a non zero constant

Tags: tangent-line

I am struggling to solve this question:

The curve $C$ has the equation 
$$ k x^2 - xy + (k+1)x=1. $$

The line $l$ has the equation 
$$ -(k/2)x + y = 1. $$

Here $k$ is a non-zero constant such that $l$ and $C$ only intersect at one point.

Find the coordinates of intersection of the line and the curve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the equation of the line, we can solve for $y$ to obtain
$$ y = (k/2)x + 1. $$
Substitute this value for $y$ into the equation of the curve to obtain
$$ k x^2 - x \left( (k/2)x + 1 \right) + (k+1) x = 1,  $$
which implies that 
$$ (k/2) x^2 + k x - 1 = 0, $$
which is a quadratic equation in $x$, and this equation has a unique solution if and only if the discriminant vanishes, that is, if and only if 
$$ k^2 + 4 (k/2) = 0, $$
which is the case if and only if 
$$ k = 0 \qquad \mbox{ or } \qquad k = -2. $$

Now we have the following two cases:

Case 1. When $k = 0$, the line has the equation 
$$ y = 1, $$
whereas the curve has the equation 
$$ -xy + x = 1. $$
Putting $y = 1$ into the equation 
$$ -xy + x = 1, $$
we obtain
$$ -x + x = 1, $$
or $0 = 1$, which is impossible. So $k$ cannot be $0$.

Case 2. When $k = -2$, the line has the equation 
$$ -x + y = 1, \tag{1} $$
whereas the curve has the equation 
$$ -2x^2 - xy - x = 1, $$
which is equivalent to 
$$ 2x^2 + xy + x = -1. \tag{2} $$
Hope you know how to solve (1) and (2) simultaneously.